# Figuring out a digit knowing that the number is a multiple of 9

Tags: self-learning

I am trying to help my kid with a homework problem, and he's insisting that the only way to solve is trial and error. I want to know if there is a more systematic way - it sounds as though the teacher may have taught them to do it by guessing and verifying, but it has stoked my curiosity.

> The cost of each item is 9 dollars. We know that some customer paid $18C43$,
>   but the figure C is blurred out. How much did we pay? and How many
>   items were purchased?

We can unfold $18C43 = 18043 + 100C$. And we know that $9n = 18043 + 100C$. But we end with have two unknowns in one equation. Of course we know that both C and n are natural numbers.

Comment: [divisibility rules](http://r.search.yahoo.com/_ylt=A0LEV7n_LCFYzGMAaiYnnIlQ;_ylu=X3oDMTEydHJwbzlsBGNvbG8DYmYxBHBvcwM0BHZ0aWQDQjI2OTFfMQRzZWMDc3I-/RV=2/RE=1478598016/RO=10/RU=https%3a%2f%2fen.wikipedia.org%2fwiki%2fDivisibility_rule/RK=0/RS=ffdwK4oumIjtoTuIMcP2AJZ0sJ0-)

Comment: $0 \le C \le 9$.

Comment: To followup on your approach: $9n = 9 \cdot(2004 + 11 C) + 7 + C$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$9n=18043+100C$
divide through by $9.$

We really only care about the remainders.

$18043/9 = (2004) r 7$

$100/ 9 = (11) r 1$

9 must divide $(7 + C)$

This approach will work for any divisor.  But 9's are special.
If the sum of the digits is divisible by 9, then the number is divisible by 9.

Answer (score 1):

*Hint:* The amount paid is a multiple of $9$. Recall casting out nines...

Solution:

Casting out nines in $18C43$ leaves $C+7$. This must be a multiple of $9$. Since $0 \le C \le 9$, we have $2 \le C+7 \le 16$, and so the only solution is $C+7=9$, that is, $C=2$.

Comment: I know the answer, and I understand that it is a multiple of nine. The issue is how structured the procedure to finding out the answer has or can be.

Comment: @Butternut Basically, you would like an explanation of the problem that can be used for kids, right?

Comment: @астонвіллаолофмэллбэрг Yes, exactly.

Answer (score 1):

keep casting out nines until you can't any more...

$18C43 \to 1+8+C+4+3 \to 16+C \to 7+C$

Then you need to have $7+C = 9$.

So $C = 2$

Why does this work?

$$18C43 =
\left\{ \begin{array}{rlo}
   10000 &= 1 + 1 \cdot 9999\\
   +8000 &= 8 + 8 \cdot 999\\
    +C00 &= C + C \cdot 99 \\
     +40 &= 4 + 4 \cdot 9 \\
      +3 &= 3
\end{array} \right.
$$
 If you examine this, you see that

\begin{align}
    18C43 
    &= 1+8+C+4+3 + (\text{a multiple of 9}) \\
    &= 16+C + (\text{a multiple of 9}) \\
    &= 1+6+C + (\text{another multiple of 9}) \\
    &= 7+C + (\text{another multiple of 9}) \\
\end{align}

So, if $18C43 $ has to be a multiple of $9$, then $7+C$ has to be a multiple of $9$.

The only choice you have is $7 + C = 9$

Answer (score 1):

$9n =18043 + 99C +C $

$n=2004 \frac 79 + 11C + \frac C9$

So $\frac 79+\frac C9=\frac {7+C}9$ is a whole number.  $C = 0....9$ so $C+7=7,....16$.  So the only possible answer is $C+7= 9$ and $C=2$

So $9n=18243$

$n=2027$

(And $2027 =2004 \frac 79+22+\frac 29$)

===

But there's also $18C43\implies 1+8+C+4+3=16+C\implies 1+6+C=7+C\implies 7+C=9$ so $C=2$ because, as everyone knows, "a number is divisible by 9 if and only if the sum of ots digits are divisible by 9".

But I have mixed feelings about teaching that to kids.  It'It's trick that kids like.  And a *really* useful one.  But I don't like teaching "magic".